# Cannot connect PostgreSQL with Python3.6 but works same code with Python2.7. Issue unexpected

Tags: python-3.x, windows, postgresql, connection, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL DB with Python on Windows, which fails using python 3.6 otherwise has success in python 2.7, the rest of code must be run in 3.6, so, that's the reason for not changing to older version.

Tried different things: I've tried to delete PORT instance, to pass connection input as variables, I've not included "conn.autocommit = True"... no luck.

I've tried to install psycopg2-binary using pip3 too:
[image: Installation CMD]
but, when I run, the issue persists.

```
def conn_to_pgdb():

    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db' user='jon' password='jon'  host='host1234' port='5444'")
    conn.autocommit = True
    cur = conn.cursor()

    create_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + con_path + ";" \
                    "CREATE TABLE " + con_path + " (" \
                    "user varchar(30)," \
                    "size varchar(50); "

    cur.execute(create_table)

conn_to_pgdb()
```

And here is the exception output:

psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "host1234" to address: Unknown server error

Comment: Does it work if you use an IP address instead of the hostname?

Comment: @BartFriederichs, I don't have an IP from the host.

Comment: Well, psycopg2 cannot look it up either. Perhaps Python 2 and 3 have different ways of getting an IP from a hostname. Can you try to `ping` the hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, and was really curious. The Virtual Environment, based on the 3.6 python interpreter was the cause of the issue. I've only changed to USE ONLY as interpreter the main Python 3.6, without creating any Virtual Environment (as I use to do)... and now works perfectly!

[image: Project interpreter]

Thanks everyone for your time,